# How to determine Daytime or Nighttime from sunrise and sunset timestamps

Tags: javascript, angular

I am implementing a weather widget in my angular application with the help of open weather api. I have used One call Api where I am getting current weather and upcoming 7 days forecast. Now for the current weather I am getting two different timestamps sunrise and sunset.

How can I determine if the current time is daytime or nighttime using those timestamps. Because based on that I will change icons in my widget.

**Current time json Object -**

```
"current":{
      "dt":1591169581,
      "sunrise":1591140098,
      "sunset":1591188490,
      "temp":35,
      "feels_like":39.04,
      "pressure":1005,
      "humidity":59,
      "dew_point":25.78,
      "uvi":13,
      "clouds":20,
      "visibility":4000,
      "wind_speed":4.1,
      "wind_deg":220,
      "weather":[
         {
            "id":721,
            "main":"Haze",
            "description":"haze",
            "icon":"50d"
         }
      ]
   },
```

Comment: Compare the sunrise/sunset times to Date.now()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var current = {
  "sunrise":1591140098,
  "sunset":1591188490,
}

if (new Date().valueOf() / 1000 < current.sunset) {
  console.log('Day Time');
} else {
  console.log('Night Time');
}
```